# Angular: Cannot read property 'setLng' of null in component variable

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm new to angular and would like to ask if why I'm encountering `Cannot read property 'setLng' of null`?

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-map',
  templateUrl: './map.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./map.component.css']
})
export class MapComponent implements OnInit {

  lat: number = 0;
  lng: number = 0;
  maptitle : string = '';

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.initMap();
  }
  initMap() {
      if (navigator) {
          navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(this.showPos);
      };
   }
  showPos(position) {
    this.setLng(position.coords.latitude);
    this.setLat(position.coords.latitude);
  }
  setLng(lng){
    this.lng = lng;
  }
  setLat(lat){
    this.lat = lat;
  }
}
```

Error

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'setLng' of null
    at webpackJsonp.../../../../../src/app/map/map.component.ts.MapComponent.showPos (map.component.ts:26)
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:388)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.js:4749)
```

Comment: You should care about `this` context, for instance `navigator.geolocation.watchPosition((pos) => this.showPos(pos))`; or `navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(this.showPos.bind(this));`

Comment: Thank you, it works like a charm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is only due to scope.

Do Something like this :

```
initMap() {
      if (navigator) {
          navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(this.showPos.bind(this));
      };
   }
```

The problem is that watchPosition expects a callback and the scope is changed .
By binding `this` , the scope is always of the class.